# ASP.net c# question on forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

Trying to create a simple form:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="register.aspx.cs" Inherits="AlphaPack._Default"
    MasterPageFile="MasterPages/Main.master"
    title="Hi there!"
%>

<script runat="server">
    public void regSubmit()
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "Submitted!";
    }
</script>

<asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="mainContent" runat="server">


<form id="registerForm" runat="server">

<asp:Label runat="server" id="statusLabel"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button id="id" text="Register" OnClick="regSubmit" runat="server" />

</form>

</asp:content>
```

hope it's obvious what I'm trying to do, someone clicks the button and it submits the form and changes the label text.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'regSubmit' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here, i'm new to .net moving over from classic ASP.

Comment: In addition to the answers, I'd recommend using the codebehind file and letting the IDE fill some of this in for you - stops you from falling foul of little problems like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void regSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: @Tom: For the record, all events in .NET have two arguments: an `Object` (whose event it is) and an `EventArgs` instance (or one of its subclasses).

Answer (score 4):

Because it's an event handler, your click method needs to have the proper signature of

```
public void regSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Jon Skeet wrote an [article on understanding Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx). Going over that may help you with these sort of issues in the future.